# access elements of a list item onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi all I'm very new to jquery and css and I'm trying to access the following:

[image: console]

I am attempting to check in the onClick function 'checkForAppointment' the values inside the 4 span tags.

html:

```
<div align="thun" id="clientScheduleWeek"  data-role="page" data-theme="a">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="a">
        <a href="#" onclick="JUMPclientDetails()">Back</a>
        <h1>Client Details</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <div id="weekViewBubble">
                <ul data-count-theme="b" data-inset="true" data-role="listview" data-theme="c">
                    <li onClick="checkForAppointment();"><a>Monday <span class="ui-li-count ui-btn-corner-all countBubl">0</span></a></li>
                    <li onClick="checkForAppointment();"><a>Tuesday <span class="ui-li-count ui-btn-corner-all countBubl">0</span></a></li>
                    <li onClick="checkForAppointment();"><a>Wednesday <span class="ui-li-count ui-btn-corner-all countBubl">0</span></a></li>
                    <li onClick="checkForAppointment();"><a>Thursday <span class="ui-li-count ui-btn-corner-all countBubl">0</span></a></li>
                    <li onClick="checkForAppointment();"><a>Friday <span class="ui-li-count ui-btn-corner-all countBubl">0</span></a></li>
                    <li onClick="checkForAppointment();"><a>Saturday <span class="ui-li-count ui-btn-corner-all countBubl">0</span></a></li>
                    <li onClick="checkForAppointment();"><a>Sunday <span class="ui-li-count ui-btn-corner-all countBubl">0</span></a></li>
                </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My starting attempt:

```
function checkForAppointment(){
    console.log('getting to the function anyway');
    var j = $('ul li').eq(0).value;
    var k = $('ul li').eq(1).value;

    console.log('j is ' + j + ' and k is '+ k);
};
```

Both j and k are undefined at this point

**EDIT:**
Function suggested by lolka_bolka:

```
function checkForAppointment(){
    var AptBool=false;
     $('.something').click(function() {
        console.log('we have entered the .click function');
        //Get all the span inside of it
        var collection = $(this).find('span');

        //Loop through all span object
        $.each(collection, function(idx, obj) {
            if ($(obj).html() > 0){
                AptBool=true;
                //return;
            }

            //Write the html value of span to the console.
            //console.log('value here is ' + $(obj).html());
        });

        if (!AptBool){
            alert('There is no appointment to view');
            return;
        }

    });


    //console.log('getting to the function anyway');
    //var j = $('ul li').eq(0).text();
    //var k = $('ul li').eq(1).text();

    //console.log('j is ' + j + ' and k is '+ k);
};
```

Comment: Is this supposed to be xml or html ? `<img>http://54.72.173.92/console.png</img>`

Comment: Show us your html please in your question, not on a picture.

Comment: All the methods in jQuery returns a jQuery object, wich is a wrapper Object for a DOM collection.. So when you call .eq(0) a jQuery Object representing a collection set of elements is returned. To get the value you can call .eq(0).val()

Comment: @Brewal it is html. It's a screenshot of chrome's console

Comment: Haaaa that makes it far more understandable.

Comment: @edrian i changed my code from .value to .val() and still j and k are undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you do not provide us a HTML code, you proved an image instead, i've just make a little example, i hope you will understand the logic of it:

**HTML**

```
<li class="something">
    Click here
    <div>
        <span>0</span>
        <span>1</span>
        <span>2</span>
        <span>3</span>
    </div>
</li>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
    //On li click where li has .something class
    $('.something').click(function() {

        //Get all the span inside of it
        var collection = $(this).find('span');

        //Loop through all span object
        $.each(collection, function(idx, obj) {
            //Write the html value of span to the console.
            console.log($(obj).html());
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I've added a bit to your function and it seems when I click on a list item, i am entering the function multiple times. I do not understand why? I'll edit my original question to show you the code

Comment: I check it. Wait for a while.

Comment: Yes. Remove the `$('.something').click(function() {` line and of its `)}` closing tag.

Comment: when I do that I am getting into the 'if' everytime.

Comment: Chek this: jsfiddle.net/9o5yLvvy/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64337/discussion-between-user2363025-and-lolka-bolka).

Comment: Sorry but i need to go soon

Comment: if you look at the image in my question you can see that each list item has 4 spans after javascript appends to the original div

Comment: before we commented out the last bit, I was getting the right response just multiple times